# Servidor para armazenar dados

Tags: banco-de-dados

Tenho uma dúvida, queria desenvolver um pequeno programa e queria que o programa tivesse um banco de dados. Inicializei o programa e queria que o banco de dados inicializasse sem que eu abrisse o xampp por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

porque você não utiliza o banco de dados SQLite com ele você não precisa de xampp e nem de wamp ele é utilizado não só para aplicação desktop mas também para plicação em android

Comment: vou experimentar, obrigado pela atenção

Comment: aqui esta o link para a biblioteca do SQLite https://www.4shared.com/file/qhrDL7Z8ce/sqlite-jdbc-372.html                        e aqui esta o link para o SGDB dele https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download  e esse link é de um video dando uma breve explicação sobre o SQLite achou que vai te ajudar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mRhx5ESTMA